# How to install FireBase Server Sdk in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add firebase server sdk library in my android app.
I inserted this code

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:[3.0.0,)' 
}
```

into build.gradle(app).
Then when I sync gradle, there comes an error message.

```
Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in project 
':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ. See 
http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
```

How can I solve this problem? 
Thank you!

Comment: Your findbugs version for app apk and test apk differ, read error message

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that both main APK and test APK share the same version of Firebase SDK.

For future reference use the error message that is provided and check out [App test conflict](http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict) as instructed.